# close jquery tooltip on esc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script to close my tooltip on clicking the close button. I need my tooltip sholud close on clicking the esc button too. How can i write the function. Here is the function that i have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// SuperNote setup: Declare a new SuperNote object and pass the name used to
// identify notes in the document, and a config variable hash if you want to
// override any default settings.

var supernote = new SuperNote('supernote', {});

// Available config options are:
//allowNesting: true/false    // Whether to allow triggers within triggers.
//cssProp: 'visibility'       // CSS property used to show/hide notes and values.
//cssVis: 'inherit'
//cssHid: 'hidden'
//IESelectBoxFix: true/false  // Enables the IFRAME select-box-covering fix.
//showDelay: 0                // Millisecond delays.
//hideDelay: 500
//animInSpeed: 0.1            // Animation speeds, from 0.0 to 1.0; 1.0 disables.
//animOutSpeed: 0.1

// You can pass several to your "new SuperNote()" command like so:
//{ name: value, name2: value2, name3: value3 }


// All the script from this point on is optional!

// Optional animation setup: passed element and 0.0-1.0 animation progress.
// You can have as many custom animations in a note object as you want.
function animFade(ref, counter)
{
 //counter = Math.min(counter, 0.9); // Uncomment to make notes translucent.
 var f = ref.filters, done = (counter == 1);
 if (f)
 {
  if (!done && ref.style.filter.indexOf("alpha") == -1)
   ref.style.filter += ' alpha(opacity=' + (counter * 100) + ')';
  else if (f.length && f.alpha) with (f.alpha)
  {
   if (done) enabled = false;
   else { opacity = (counter * 100); enabled=true }
  }
 }
 else ref.style.opacity = ref.style.MozOpacity = counter*0.999;
};
supernote.animations[supernote.animations.length] = animFade;



// Optional custom note "close" button handler extension used in this example.
// This picks up click on CLASS="note-close" elements within CLASS="snb-pinned"
// notes, and closes the note when they are clicked.
// It can be deleted if you're not using it.
addEvent(document, 'click', function(evt)
{
 var elm = evt.target || evt.srcElement, closeBtn, note;

 while (elm)
 {
  if ((/note-close/).test(elm.className)) closeBtn = elm;
  if ((/snb-pinned/).test(elm.className)) { note = elm; break }
  elm = elm.parentNode;
 }

 if (closeBtn && note)
 {
  var noteData = note.id.match(/([a-z_\-0-9]+)-note-([a-z_\-0-9]+)/i);
  for (var i = 0; i < SuperNote.instances.length; i++)
   if (SuperNote.instances[i].myName == noteData[1])
   {
    setTimeout('SuperNote.instances[' + i + '].setVis("' + noteData[2] +
     '", false, true)', 100);
    cancelEvent(evt);
   }
 }
});


// Extending the script: you can capture mouse events on note show and hide.
// To get a reference to a note, use 'this.notes[noteID]' within a function.
// It has properties like 'ref' (the note element), 'trigRef' (its trigger),
// 'click' (whether its shows on click or not), 'visible' and 'animating'.
addEvent(supernote, 'show', function(noteID)
{
 // Do cool stuff here!
});
addEvent(supernote, 'hide', function(noteID)
{
 // Do cool stuff here!
});


// If you want draggable notes, feel free to download the "DragResize" script
// from my website http://www.twinhelix.com -- it's a nice addition :).

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the document's keydown and check whether the ESC key is pressed. Then you can write your custom code for closing the tooltip inside the callback..

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27) {
     // close the tooltip
     var note = $('.snb-pinned');
     var noteData = note.id.match(/([a-z_\-0-9]+)-note-([a-z_\-0-9]+)/i);

     for (var i = 0; i < SuperNote.instances.length; i++)

     if (SuperNote.instances[i].myName == noteData[1]) 
     {    
       setTimeout('SuperNote.instances[' + i + '].setVis("' + noteData[2] +   
       '", false, true)', 100);           
      }    
     }
   });
```

Comment: I am just a beginner in jquery. Can you please provide the custom code for closing the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your code. But still it doesn't close on esc.